# Make \phantomsection get me where links to chapter usually do

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

I have such code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\specnodala}[1]{\newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}\section*{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\specnodala{Izmantotie}
\specnodala{Ievads}

\end{document}
```

The links (from bookmarks or table of contents) lead me to the heading, but I want it to get me a bit higher like it does with a chapter. I tried adding `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before `\phantomsection`. It made linking to the second chapter nicer, but changed nothing about the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are using an ancient version of `hyperref`, it is usually enough to put `\addcontentsline` after your starred `\section`. `hyperref` then uses the anchor of the previous `\section` for the table of contents and the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% bookmarks get faster updated

\newcommand{\specnodala}[1]{%
  \newpage % or \clearpage, if previous float objects should not float into the next section
  \section*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\specnodala{Izmantotie}
\specnodala{Ievads}

\end{document}
```

The destination names for the two `\specnodala` are `section*.2` and `section*.3` with the following positions (`x` × `y`) after compiling with `pdflatex`:

```
section*.2: 133.768 × 675.168
section*.3: 133.768 × 675.168
```

Thus the positions are the same *exactly*.

Comment: This also doesn't give the same result for both `\specnodala{}`s

Comment: @Juris This is perhaps an effect of your PDF browser or its view settings. The destination positions are the same exactly, see the updated answer.

Comment: You're right @Heiko

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `\specnodala` to jump vertically to the location you want *before* setting `\phantomsection`, and then jump back. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\newcommand{\specnodala}[1]{%
  \clearpage%
  \vspace*{-1in}\phantomsection\vspace*{1in}% Hyperlink reference is set 1in above heading
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}\section*{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\specnodala{Izmantotie}
\specnodala{Ievads}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It affects the first of chapters, but does nothing with the second (it still leads to the top of that page). Also why are you using `\clearpage` in place of `\newpage`?

Comment: @Juris: I don't understand. In my example (similar to your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)), both the ToC and the bookmarks jump to 1in above the `\specnodala` (which is set as a `\section*` in the text, but as a `chapter` in the ToC). How does my solution "only affect the first chapters, and not the second"?

Comment: Using `\clearpage` is better to flush all floats that are waiting to be processed.

Comment: For me it jumps to "Izmantotie" as desired, but clicking "Ievads" takes me to the top of the page where "Ievads" is.

Comment: @Juris: You state in your question you want it to jump "a bit higher", like in "Ievads" I assumed. I may have misunderstood your question then?

Comment: I would enjoy if "Ievads" and "Izmantotie" would both behave the same way, but they don't (at least for me).

Comment: @Juris The position of destination `section*.2` for "levads" is 133.768 bp × 729.235 bp and the position of destination `section*.6` for "lzmantotie" is 133.768 bp × 729.235 bp. Both are the same *exactly*.

Comment: @Juris Probably you are using Adobe Reader with continuous page display setting. Depending on the window height and scale settings the PDF viewer cannot view the start of the next page after the latest page with "Ievads" and therefore moves the view area. If you want to test the vertical component of destination settings you need non-continuous settings, small window height and larger zoom settings.